# Need the Sql Query Like this format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my query

```
SELECT  *,'WESTRAC - T120' AS [Dealer Code] FROM [CPO by wesTrac by Customers] WHERE [CPO by wesTrac by Customers].[Dealer Breakdown] LIKE 'T080 - N%'
```

run this i get like this

```
Dealer  Customer    Dealer Breakdown    Type    2012/Jan    2012/Feb 2012/Mar 2012/Apr  2012/May    2012/Jun    2012/Jul    2012/Aug    2012/Sep    2012/Oct    2012/Nov    2012/Dec

WESTRAC - T080  A.P.Delaney & Co    T080 - N165580 - apdelaney  PS WEB  0   189 19  0   20  78  0   0   92  0   0   0
```

But i need the output like this:

```
Dealer         TYPE     DEALER BREAKDOWN           DEALERCODE       DATE       Oniline Sales
WESTRAC-T080  PSWEB      T080-N165580-apdelaney    WESTRAC-T120     2012/Jan     0
WESTRAC-T080  PSWEB      T080-N165580-apdelaney    WESTRAC-T120     2012/Feb     189
WESTRAC-T080  PSWEB      T080-N165580-apdelaney    WESTRAC-T120     2012/Mar     19
---
---
---
WESTRAC-T080  PSWEB      T080-N165580-apdelaney    WESTRAC-T120     2012/Dec     0
```

Comment: That is the where condtion

Comment: only that values with that it will filter and then based on that i need the query

Comment: Oh, you're trying to `Pivot` your results?  Well `UnPivot` them?

Comment: is there any other option rather than pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like you are trying to `unpivot` your results.  Here is a condensed version (you'll need to specify all your columns):

```
SELECT dealer, 
       type, 
       dealerbreakdown, 
       'WESTRAC - T120' dealercode, 
       dealerdate, 
       onlinesales 
FROM   dealerbreakdown 
       UNPIVOT ( onlinesales 
               FOR dealerdate IN ([2012/Jan], 
                                  [2012/Feb], 
                                  [2012/Mar]) ) u
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b0aa/3)